# jsbn library BigInteger negate function seems not working

Tags: javascript, biginteger, jsbn

I am using the jsbn library to manage BigIntegers in a javascript application.
It seems that the negate function is not working well.

I expect that the negate function works like the Java one.

```
BigInteger minusOne = BigInteger.ONE.negate(); // -1
```

But with the jsbn library the following code produce this result...

```
var BigInteger = require('jsbn').BigInteger;

var bi = BigInteger.ONE;
console.log(bi); // 1
console.log(bi.negate()); // 268435455 but should be -1, no ??
```

You can try this code here https://runkit.com/gikoo/jsbn-negate-function/1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigInteger is storing numbers in a way that allows them to track numbers bigger than what JavaScript can track.  How they do that you should consider a black box - when you are ready to go back to a normal int, you need to do `bi.negate().intValue()`, or if it really is too big, `bi.negate().toString()`

https://runkit.com/davidjwilkins/example-bigint

Comment: Thank you! I was wrong, I was looking at the representation of the value in jsbn instead of dealing with the value directly.